# Determine Forecast Horizon in Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to test out the Forecasting prediction in Azure Automated ML UX (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-create-portal-experiments). **However, I am a bit confused about what "Forecast Horizon" means.** *The hint says "Forecasting expects periodic data (e.g. daily, weekly). Horizon is how many periods forward you would like to forecast." - and it must be an integer.* I have a test dataset that increments every 1 hr. **So does that mean "Forcast Horizon" should be set to 1?**

Here is some of my test dataset:

```
Hour                Brightness
2019-08-06 00-00-00 0
2019-08-06 01-00-00 0
2019-08-06 02-00-00 0
2019-08-06 03-00-00 0
2019-08-06 04-00-00 0
2019-08-06 05-00-00 0
2019-08-06 06-00-00 0
2019-08-06 07-00-00 0
2019-08-06 08-00-00 100
2019-08-06 09-00-00 100
2019-08-06 10-00-00 100
2019-08-06 11-00-00 100
2019-08-06 12-00-00 0
2019-08-06 13-00-00 0
2019-08-06 14-00-00 0
2019-08-06 15-00-00 0
2019-08-06 16-00-00 0
2019-08-06 17-00-00 100
2019-08-06 18-00-00 100
2019-08-06 19-00-00 40
2019-08-06 20-00-00 40
2019-08-06 21-00-00 40
2019-08-06 22-00-00 0
2019-08-06 23-00-00 0
2019-08-07 00-00-00 0
2019-08-07 01-00-00 0
2019-08-07 02-00-00 0
2019-08-07 03-00-00 0
2019-08-07 04-00-00 0
```

[Screenshot in Azure Automated ML UX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3jnp.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Forecasting expects periodic data (e.g. daily, weekly).

This means your data should be kind of repetitive. Meaning, it shows similar patters for example every week. Let's see the visitors in a store show the same curve every week (low on Monday...high on Wednesday...low on Friday ... none on Sunday... low on Monday...high on Wednesday...and so on)

So in this case your period would be Weekly.

> Horizon is how many periods forward you would like to forecast

So horizon means in this case, how many weeks ahead you would like to forecast. If you set it to 1, only one week ahead will be forecasted. If you set it to 4, you'll get 4 weeks for forecasts back.

Comment: For my data posted above, would Azure figure out I want my period to be hourly? I tried to set Forecast Horizon to 24 (24 hrs of forecast), but it gave an error of "[AttributeError][Unclassified]Message hidden."

Comment: Hm not sure, the error is not very helpful. However, what format is your data in? CSV with space-limited? It looks like date and time are two separate fields. Can you maybe transform it in one field, for example with an ISO-encoded timestamp? Maybe the space between date and time is confusing the system

Comment: I've tried using yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' format as well as a Unix Epoch format, but neither work  - both result in the same error.

Comment: where exactly do you see this error? I just tried to repro with your sample data and so far my AutoML job runs fine. I copied your data into a text file and made a TSV out of it.

Comment: Can I ask what your "advanced settings" were?

Comment: I didn’t change anything there from the defaults